# Python crontab creates an entry in wrong format

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cron

I use following code to schedule a task, but the Crontab entry it produces is in wrong format.

```
def main(): 
   from crontab import CronTab
   cron = CronTab(user=True)
   job = cron.new(command='python /home/niroshan/repos/maisie/Tests/dummyprint.py')
   job.minute.on(2)
   cron.write()
```

When I execute `crontab -e` I can see following crontab entry, but the script does not get called.

`2 * * * * python /home/niroshan/repos/maisie/Tests/dummyprint.py`

After some googling I manually changed the entry to look like below and it started working.

`*/2 * * * * python /home/niroshan/repos/maisie/Tests/dummyprint.py`

How do I get python to create the entry in correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
job.minute.every(2)
```

`on` triggers the command 'on' the minute, i.e. 1:02, 2:02, etc.